# posts_per_page plus show specific number per category

Tags: wordpress

I have a small custom loop in the works, but I'm running into a small problem with it.  Here is my current loop:

```
<?php

    $cats = get_categories();

    foreach ($cats as $cat) {

        $cat_id= $cat->term_id;

        query_posts("cat=$cat_id,-8&posts_per_page=10&order=ASC");

        if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post();
?>

     <?php the_title(); ?>
     <br/>

<?php endwhile; endif; } ?>
```

The loop works, and sorts the posts by category as intended, but I need to **always** show 3 posts per page from each category.  My question is how to add arguments to the `query_posts` that will allow for there to always be 3 posts per page per category,for a total of 12 posts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This loop is actually doing what I want it to do already.  Using the foreach loop it is iterating a loop for each category, and the `posts_per_page` is working for each loop inside the foreach loop.  Hopefully that makes sense.

Comment: change the parameter posts_per_page  in loop to 3

Comment: Yes, I know that already.  I answered my own question actually.  I got a bit hasty with asking it without first realizing that it was already doing what I wanted it to do.  Thanks.  Its all good, working as intended.